# How does working directory work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, working-directory

In Visual Studio, you are provided the option to change the working directory. I understand how to use it, but I do not know how it works.

How does the working directory setting work in relation to the complication of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if a program tries to open a file using relative directories (like e.g. `"dir\\file.ext"`) then that relative directory is from the programs working directory. The working directory doesn't have to be the directory where the program is located, and the working directory can be changed from inside the program with e.g. the [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Another example: Lets say you are starting a program from a command prompt window, and you are in the directory `C:\some\folder\`. The program is located in `D:\other\folder\`. Since the current directory when you start the program is `C:\some\folder\`, the programs working directory will be that as well.

Comment: I understand that, but what does the compiler do with the 'working directory' setting? i.e. Does it insert a call to SetCurrentDirectory in my code implicitly?

Comment: @ThomasC The compiler does nothing with it, it's when Visual Studio starts your program that it (Visual Studio) simply changes to that directory before running your program. Much like the second paragraph in my answer. It's not encoded in your program in any way.

Comment: Ah, I misread the second paragraph slightly, sorry. That taught me something new about the command line too. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasC: Note that the "Working Directory" setting in Visual Studio is located in the "Debugging" tab.